# Como poder controlar el numero de items que se ve de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview

Como la pregunta lo dice tengo mi `RecyclerView` lleno con 50 elementos aproximadamente los cuales por defecto se muestran pero lo que busco es poder darle un numero especifico que elementos que quiero que se vean,se que el `getItemCount()` controla dicho numero de items lo que no se es como hacerlo dinámico con un simple `EditText`

Mi **adaptador** es este

```
public class Adaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.CartaViewHolder> {
private Context contexto;
private List<Contenido> listacartas;

public Adaptador(Context contexto, List<Contenido> listacartas) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.listacartas = listacartas;
}

@Override
public CartaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflado = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    View vistosa = inflado.inflate(R.layout.cartas, null);
    return new CartaViewHolder(vistosa);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CartaViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Contenido datos = listacartas.get(position);

    holder.nombre.setText(datos.getNombre());
    holder.imagen.setImageDrawable(contexto.getResources().getDrawable(datos.getImagen()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listacartas.size();
}

class CartaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imagen;
    TextView nombre;

    public CartaViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

Mi **mainActivity** donde tengo el `edittext` para dar el numero exacto de items a la `recycle`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button click;
BlankFragment blankFragment;
EditText numero;
RecyclerView reciclador;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    click = findViewById(R.id.fragmento);
    numero = findViewById(R.id.numero);

    blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
    findViewById(R.id.fragmento).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.contenedor, blankFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            click.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            numero.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    click.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    numero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Y el fragment donde lleno la lista que se muestra en el `recicleView` la cual necesito recudir el numero de `items` que se muestra

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView reciclador;
List<Contenido> listota;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
        = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    listota = new ArrayList<>();

    reciclador = view.findViewById(R.id.Lista);
    reciclador.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    reciclador.setHasFixedSize(true);
    reciclador.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.alacran, "Alacran"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.apache, "Apache"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.arana, "Araña"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.arbol, "Arbol"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.arpa, "Arpa"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.bandera, "Bandera"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.barril, "Barril"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.borracho, "Borracho"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.bota, "Bota"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.botella, "Botella"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.calavera, "Calavera"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.camaron, "Camaron"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.campana, "Campana"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.cantaro, "Catrin"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.cazo, "Cazo"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.chalupa, "Chalupa"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.corazon, "Corazon"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.corona, "Corona"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.cotorro, "Cotorro"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.dama, "Dama"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.diablito, "Diablito"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.escalera, "Escalera"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.estrella, "Estrella"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.gallo, "Gallo"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.garza, "Garza"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.gorrito, "Gorrito"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.jaras, "Jarras"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.luna, "Luna"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.maceta, "Maceta"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.mano, "Mano"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.melon, "Melon"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.muerte, "Muerte"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.mundo, "Mundo"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.musico, "Musico"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.negro, "Negro"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.nopal, "Nopal"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.pajaro, "Pajaro"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.palma, "Palma"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.paragauas, "Paraguas"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.pera, "Pera"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.pescado, "Pescado"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.pino, "Pino"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.rana, "Rana"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.rosa, "Rosa"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.sandolon, "Sandolon"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.sandria, "Sandia"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.sirena, "Sirena"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.sol, "Sol"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.soldado, "Soldado"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.tambor, "Tambor"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.valiente, "Valiente"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.venado, "Venado"));
    listota.add(new Contenido(R.drawable.violoncelo, "Violonchelo"));



    Adaptador adapter = new Adaptador(getContext(), listota);

    reciclador.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Podrías explicar porque no quieres mostrar ciertos elementos? O que características tienen los elementos que no se deberían de mostrar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar el metodo `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Entonces en tu `editText` obtienes con el `textWatcher` el texto y ahi mandas a actualizar tu adaptador.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try{
            int numItems = Integer.parseInt(s);
            adapter.setNumItems(numItems);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch(Exception e){
             //no es numero
        }
    }
```

y en tu `adapter` agregas un metodo `setNumItems` (o como lo quieras llamar) y seteas el num de items que dice el editText y cambias el valor de items desplegados en `getItemCount`

```
public class Adaptador......
    private int numItems;

    public Adaptador(Context contexto, List<Contenido> listacartas) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.listacartas = listacartas;
        this.numItems = listacartas.size(); //por default muestra todos, aca le cambias a un valor fijo o como lo necesites
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //igual y valida aca que numItems sea <= listacartas.size() para que no provoque error
        return numItems;
    }

    void setNumItems(int numItems){
        this.numItems = numItems;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!